# Removing bootstrap table rows using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve a table which allows the user to delete specific rows; Using JavaScript and bootstrap. I used the canonic way, but it seems to not work:`

```
<form action="scrivi.php" method="POST">    
    <table class="table" id="tab">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Docente</th>
          <th scope="col">Prima ora</th>
          <th scope="col">Seconda ora</th>
          <th scope="col">Terza ora</th>
          <th scope="col">Quarta ora</th>
          <th scope="col">Quinta</th>
          <th scope="col">Sesta ora</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php                  
          echo sprintf('<td><button type="button" onClick="rimuovi(0)">Submit</button></td>');
      ?>             
      </tbody> 
    </table>
```

the JavaScript function:

```
fuction rimuovi(i){
    var table = getElementById("tab").deleteRow(0);
}
```

I know that I could fix the problem using google Ajax, but I remember that there is an easier way to solve it. I tried everything I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working example

```js
const table = document.getElementById('tab')

table.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()=="button")
{
 table.querySelector("tbody").removeChild(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
}


})
```

```html
<table class="table" id="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Docente</th>
      <th scope="col">Prima ora</th>
      <th scope="col">Seconda ora</th>
      <th scope="col">Terza ora</th>
      <th scope="col">Quarta ora</th>
      <th scope="col">Quinta</th>
      <th scope="col">Sesta ora</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
        <td><button>delet</button> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td><button>delet</button> </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td>hey </td>
       <td><button>delet</button> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you. You have been so helpful.